# Select dates from a table based on date range of another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

Database Flavour: PostgreSQL 9.5

I'm trying to get my head around getting dates in table1 which are in the range of dates of the `debtors.debt_date` field i.e. dates between (-3 and + 4 days of a given date in the `debtors.debt_date` field)

Query 1 gives me:

> ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
>   (which is no surprise)

```
select table1.sale_date
from sales table1 where 
table1.sale_date between 
    (select debt_date::date -3 from debtors) 
and (select debt_date::date +4 from debtors);
```

Query 2 returns no rows (and I think the where initial where clause is looking for absolute values)

```
select table1.sale_date
from sales table1 where 
table1.sale_date in ( 
    (select debt_date::date from debtors where debt_date between   
     debt_date::date - 3 and  debt_date::date + 4);
```

Comment: Unrelated, but: what data type is `debt_date`?  why are you casting that to a date?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name the debt_date type is `timestamp without time zone ` and what i'm trying to do is to subtract 3 and add 4 days from the debtors.date_paid since I'm interested in dates from the sales tables that fall within that range in the debtors table.

Comment: Probably: `... from sales s join debtors d on (s.sale_date between d.debt_date - '3 day'::interval and d.debt_date + '4 day'::interval)`. Sorry, it is not so clear about table/column names...

Comment: Thanks ..that's spot on and has addressed the original question

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to do ?

```
select table1.sale_date
from sales table1 
where  table1.sale_date between debt_date::date -3 AND debt_date::date +4
```

Comment: Thanks but it's more like

`select table1.sale_date
from sales table1 
where  table1.sale_date between debtors.debt_date::date -3 AND debtors.debt_date::date +4`

Comment: I don't understand, debt_date::date is a column or a paramater ?

Comment: `select debt_date  from debtors limit 1; (timestamp without time zone without casting )
debt_date      
---------------------
2013-05-13 00:00:00
 
pgdb=# select debt_date::date from debtors limit 1;  (Cast only dates, I'm not interested in the time)
debt_date  
------------
2013-05-13
(1 row)

pgdb=#  select debt_date::date + 4  from debtors limit 1;  (Cast dates and add/subtract for my purposes)
?column?  
------------
2013-05-17
(1 row)`

Comment: `select debt_date  from debtors limit 1; `
(timestamp without time zone without casting )
debt_date      
---------------------
2013-05-13 00:00:00
 
`pgdb=# select debt_date::date from debtors limit 1;  `(Cast only dates, I'm not interested in the time)
debt_date  
------------
2013-05-13
(1 row)

pgdb=#  select debt_date::date + 4  from debtors limit 1;  (Cast dates and add/subtract for my purposes)
?column?  
------------
2013-05-17
(1 row)

Comment: Sorry, formatted further for readability 

(timestamp without time zone without casting )
`select debt_date  from debtors limit 1;` 
`debt_date`      
`---------------------`
`2013-05-13 00:00:00`
 
 (Cast only dates, I'm not interested in the time)
`pgdb=# select debt_date::date from debtors limit 1;`  
`debt_date ` 
`------------`
`2013-05-13`

(Cast dates and add/subtract for my purposes)
`pgdb=#  select debt_date::date + 4  from debtors limit 1; ` 
`?column?  `
------------
`2013-05-17`